# Invalid connection string with jruby and oracle_enhaced adaptor

Tags: oracle, jruby

I've configured my rails app's database like the following.

```
test:
  adapter: oracle_enhanced
  host: localhost
  database: localhost:1521/xe
  username: test
  password: test
  pool: 50
  wait_timeout: 10
  tns: xe
```

It works using REE and oracled_enhanced adapter but doesn't work with jruby and instead gives the following error:

```
% rake spec
(in /home/xxxxxxxx)
rake aborted!
java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Invalid connection string format, a valid format is: "host:port:sid"
```

I haven't yet been able to get it print the actual connection string that it tries to use. Running rake with `--trace` doesn't help either. Any ideas how I could get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this connection string:

```
test:
  adapter: oracle_enhanced
  driver: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
  url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
  ...
```

That format works for me
/Mads

Answer (score 0):

In my case this issue was resolved by making sure both `ORACLE_HOME` and `TNS_ADMIN` environment variables were set to the instant client installation directory:

```
$ echo $ORACLE_HOME
/Library/Oracle/instantclient/11.2.0.3.0
$ echo $TNS_ADMIN
/Library/Oracle/instantclient/11.2.0.3.0
```